# Sails.js custom route with same controller but different layouts

Tags: routes, sails.js, ejs, custom-routes

today Im here to not just check good answers, but ask!
I want to do the following using Sails.js and its routes.js:

[image: My problem picture]

What I want is to actually provide different layouts based on the type of user that is logged in. I know how to do that, but I dont want to write this on the `routes.js` file (because it is messy and I dont want to create controllers to do the job of the route itself):

```
'get /adminSpace/*' : {
    controller : 'adminSpace' //setting layout on controller
},
'get /userSpace/*' : {
    controller : 'userSpace' // //setting layout on controller
}
```

A quick way, if possible, would be to write it like this:

```
'get /[user|admin]/projects/*' : {
    controller : 'project'
    locals: {
      layout: 'based_on_url'
}}
```

Is this by any way possible?

Comment: Just to be clear, I dont want to add the middleman-like AdminSpaceController and UserSpaceController to set up the layout! And then specializing each controller url for each role. Any tips?

Comment: Sails routes can do some pretty tricky stuff: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes but my instincts say to me, why not user your controller? I'm not sure if locals set in the routes file can access wildcards (like [user|admin] etc) drawn from the route itself, or other dynamic data.

Comment: I also feel like two routes may be simpler! Other devs looking at your code could certainly understand two routes more quickly than having to unparse the funny syntax used to put regex's into the routes.

Comment: Well, the general idea that I have is this: solve the type of user -> use the appropriate controller by the model. If cant do that, then I need to repeat a chunk of code like `if(requester == admin) { (set layout here)} else {}` for every controller action. See my point? What I want is a common place to put this and then use my controllers with no knowledge of the layout needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I'm reading what you want based on the comments - you want different behaviour for normal and admin users. You'll have code to handle this in your `routes.js` file, and in your `views`, but you'd like the controllers to get to ignore the difference - they can do their thing without bothering to detect "admin vs normal".

You can do that by setting locals on two different routes pointing to the same controller:

```
'GET /adminSpace/*' : {
    controller : 'UserController',
    locals: {
        admin: true,
        _layoutFile: 'admin'
    }
},
'GET /userSpace/*' : {
    controller : 'UserController', // same as above
    locals: {
        admin: false,
        _layoutFile: 'user'
    }
},
```

Then in your `UserController`:

```
someAction: function(req, res) {
    // any logic needed
    // can access sails.locals.admin if necessary, but do not have to
    return res.view(); // will use admin.ejs or users.ejs as set in route
}
```

In your view, the locals set in the route will still be accessible, and you can add extra locals in the controller if needed. Hope this was what you were looking for!